# How to create a payment with a `SetupIntents`?

Tags: stripe-payments

`SetupIntents` from https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents is described as:

> A SetupIntent guides you through the process of setting up and saving a customer's payment credentials for future payments.

but I cannot find any documentation for how to use a created `SetupIntent` to create a payment.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse for instance creates the `SetupIntent` but under https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#charge-saved-payment-method it doesn't use it.

It only uses the created payment method id (a card in this case) and customer id.

1. create customer
2. create card
3. create setup intent
4. create payment with customer + card

It seems I only need to create the customer and payment method, is this correct? What is the point of `SetupIntent` if it's unused?

In my current situation I have the customer and card details, and I want to set up the customer such that the system them in the future.

Answer (score 0):

SetupIntent is just to collect the payment method details and save to the customer if [`customer`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/create#create_setup_intent-customer) is set. SetupIntent can't create a payment and won't be needed anymore after SetupIntent is completed successfully. The payment method ID (pm_xxx) created from SetupIntent is the main result that can be used for future payment.

If you wish to create the payment after the payment method (with ID starts with `pm_`) is collected with SetupIntent, creating a Payment Intent with `payment_method` is required like this [step](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse?platform=web#charge-saved-payment-method) mentioned in the guide.

If you wish to save the payment method during payment, `SetupIntent` is not required. You may set [`setup_future_usage`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-setup_future_usage) in Payment Intent: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-during-payment

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your answer, could you give an example? Maybe of setting up a customer with a card payment method, then charging said customer.

Comment: My example would be the same as code examples in the [guide](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) that: set up a card using SetupIntent > collect the payment method details in Payment Element > create PaymentMethod (pm_xxx) and save to the customer > create PaymentIntent to charge to customer with the saved PaymentMethod (pm_xxx). Is there any specific step that you have question or concern with?

Comment: I am not using a Payment Element I am doing this entirely through the API, this is the key disconnect, this is where an example would be useful.

Comment: How do you collect the payment method details? Payment Element provides hosted form to embed inside your website to collect payment method details. If you don't have one, then you'd need to manually set those payment method details in [`payment_method_data`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents/create#create_setup_intent-payment_method_data) hash of SetupIntent API depending the payment method chosen.